# Problem booting Ubuntu 15.04 on SSD

Tags: boot

I installed Ubuntu 15.04 on my SSD a few days ago, and this morning I removed my HDD with Windows 8.1 to see if Ubuntu would boot. It didn't. I put the HDD back in and restarted, but with no avail. Ubuntu didn't boot.

Ubuntu would show the purple screen before Windows Boot Manager if this helps.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

You likely have the drive mounted in `/etc/fstab` using `/dev/sdX` and the identifying letter got changed. Drives get assigned a letter by the order they are found. Make a live USB stick and fix your `/etc/fstab`.

```
lsblk
```

will show the drives.

Also, its a good habit to mount drives in `/etc/fstab` using an UUID rather than `/dev/sdX`. You can find out the UUIDs with

```
sudo blkid
```

Comment: Sorry for no response!! I got it working after visiting another thread which I tried before posting, but forgot to use cmd in Administrative mode. I typed "bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi" (without the " ") and now I can switch btwn OSs without hassle.